# C compiler relocates pointer that overlaps another variable

Tags: c

I am doing some experiments to see how C allocates variables on the stack. I am getting some odd behavior with the following code. C appears to be growing the stack downward, so in the following example, the char c is allocated in the byte immediately before the short s. I then create an int pointer `bigRandP` and point it at the same location occupied by c, so the "int" it sees overlaps with the space on the stack occupied by s. I then try to assign something to the location referenced by the int pointer.

```
unsigned short nameSum = 0;
unsigned char smallRand = 0;
unsigned int* bigRandP;

//The "int" pointed to by iP should overlap s
bigRandP = (unsigned int*)(&smallRand);
printf("%p %p %p\n", &nameSum, &smallRand, bigRandP);
printf("%u %u %u\n", smallRand, nameSum, *bigRandP);
*bigRandP = 0;
printf("%p %p %p\n", &nameSum, &smallRand, bigRandP);
printf("%u %u %u\n", smallRand, nameSum, *bigRandP);

0028FF1A 0028FF19 0028FF19
0 0 419430400
0028FF1A 0028FF19 0028FF00
0 0 4210788
```

The printed results are interesting. Not only does the assignment fail (the int pointed to by bigRandP is not set to 0), the int pointer itself is silently *relocated* to point somewhere else further down the stack. What is going on? Is this the C compiler's way of keeping me from overwriting other variables with overlapping pointers?

Comment: As a pedantic matter "c" does not allocate variables on "the stack". The language doesn't have a notion of "the stack" but rather of "automatic variables" (which are essentially always implemented by allocation on a stack). Each compiler has it's own strategy for building stack frames and is simply required to make sure that variables behave as the standard says.

Comment: A `char` will typically occupy a word on the stack, you might be stepping on the "wrong" end of that (for your purposes, that is).

Comment: And the order in which variables within a function are allocated isn't necessarily related to the direction in which the stack grows, even on systems (most of them) where the latter is meaningful. Typically everything defined inside a function, or at least inside a block, will be allocated in one fell swoop by adjusting the stack pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bigRandP` is a pointer to `unsigned int`.

You pointed it to an `unsigned char` object, then you *modified* the `unsigned int` object that `bigRandP` points to.

Apparently `smallRand` and `bigRandP` are stored close to each other in memory. By trying to modify `sizeof (unsigned int)` bytes of a 1-byte object, you clobbered part of the pointer object itself.

Bottom line: Your program's behavior is undefined.

Also, though this probably isn't related to the behavior you're seeing, the `%p` format requires a `void*` argument. If you want to print some other type of pointer, you should convert it to `void*`:

```
printf("%p %p %p\n", (void*)&nameSum, (void*)&smallRand, (void*)bigRandP);
```

It's likely to "work" with or without the casts on systems where all pointers have the same representation, but the version with the casts is more correct on all systems.